# line from file as separate string for function

Tags: python

I found similar examples of my issue however i could not successfully implement in my example.

I have file with one URL domain at each line. I want to execute a function for each domain in the file.

This is my code:

```
    hostname = [line.rstrip() for line in open('domains')]

    def checkcert():
            with socket.create_connection((hostname, port)) as sock:
                with context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname = hostname) as ssock:
    
                    certificate = ssock.getpeercert()
                    certExpires = datetime.datetime.strptime(certificate['notAfter'], '%b %d %H:%M:%S %Y %Z')

for line in hostname:
    checkcert()
```

For now the hostname variable contains all of the domains at the same time. So if i print out this variable it will give me the full file.

What is the easiest way to strip the file so i can check the certificate for each of them? Do i need to iterate in the loop or there is simpler method?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know hat you mean "better way". If you mean faster try parallelizing your code either with multiprocessing or multithreading. For example

```
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers = 10) as executor:
    results = executor.map(checkcert, hostname)
    
for result in results:
      print(result)
```

you should see a great performance improvement orders of magnitude maybe.

Comment: Sorry for confusion. I meant my code is not even working, i dont know how to load each line separately.